# Remove Basic Error Controller In SpringFox SwaggerUI

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

Is there a way i can remove the "basic-error-controller" from springfox swagger-ui?

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can restrict the request handler selector to scan only the package of your project:

```
    return new Docket( DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis( RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage( "your package" ) )
        ...
```

Comment: for anyone who isn't familiar with what to fill in for "your package", it's the folder name right underneath `java`

Comment: That wasn't needed. Sometimes it's not clear what someone means when there's just text that doesn't look like the real value. Also, even though, they probably could have figured it out from reading the docs or the code, not everyone is as amazing as you.

Comment: Why was even the basic error controller added? Is it because when there is no controller to show something in swagger?

Answer (score 46):

I think, the most elegant solution is to include only `@RestController` controllers into swagger, only thing to bear in mind, is to annotate all the REST controllers with that annotation:

```
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
```

As `BasicErrorController` is annotated with `@Controller` only, swagger would avoid `BasicErrorController` in definition file. Of course you can use your custom annotation instead of `@RestController` to mark your REST controllers as controllers eligible by swagger.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMO.

Answer (score 27):

- It can be done using **Predicate.not()** .

  ```
   @Bean
   public Docket api() {
       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
           .select()
           .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
           .paths(PathSelectors.any())
           .paths(Predicate.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
           .build();
   }
  ```

Answer (score 9):

For example if your parent Package is com.app.microservice

```
package com.app.microservice;
```

Then use the following code it will only display the Controllers within the Package and disable/exclude others

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.app.microservice"))
                .build();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

U can also use springfox-swagger2 annotations. springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore

```
@ApiIgnore
public class ErrorController {
```

This would exclude that class from documentation.

Comment: `BasicErrorController` is library functions, so cannot be easily annotated with `@ApiIgnore`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was just that I forgot to annotate Docket api() method with @Bean.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by moving `@Bean` definition to main class (the one with `@SpringBootApplication`) and use its `this.getClass().getPackageName()` in `basePackage()`:

```
@Bean
public Docket swagger() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(this.getClass().getPackageName()))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swagger.v3, we can use `@Hidden`.  So:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  @Hidden // Don't show in the Swagger doco
  @ResponseBody
  public void handleError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // My handler code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of solutions, nothing works for me. Finally I got to know the very basic thing i.e. make sure that the file in which you have defined your ***swagger configuration file and your main method file***  should be in the ***same package*** .

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
    .build();
}
```

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E58MP.png)

Comment: It will work fine even if they are in different packages. These is no such constraint like the one you have posted.

Comment: If your configuration bean files are in different packages, then you have to use **@componentScan("base-package")** annotation on your main method.

Comment: We also can use "import" annotation so that SwaggerConfig class can be imported in the main class.