# Remove resources automatically added by FF4J

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ff4j

recently i have added FF4j dependency on my application, after that new resource end points have appeared in my swagger ui, is there any way to disable these end points?

[image]

the dependency add was

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>ff4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Comment: Do you only want to remove them from the API documentation, or disable the endpoints completely?

Comment: from the api documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SpringDoc:

```
springdoc.packages-to-exclude=com.unwantedPackage
```

If you are using SpringFox:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().paths(Predicate.not(PathSelectors.regex("/api/ff4j/store.*")).apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.package.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
```

[Remove Basic Error Controller In SpringFox SwaggerUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941917/remove-basic-error-controller-in-springfox-swaggerui)